# How do I redirect output when the command to execute is stored in a variable in a bash script?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Consider the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD="echo hello world > /tmp/hello.out"
${CMD}
```

The output for this is:

```
hello world > /tmp/hello.out
```

How can I modify CMD so that the output gets redirected to hello.out?
For my use case, it is not feasible to either do this:

```
 ${CMD} > /tmp/hello.out
```

or to add this at the top of the script:

```
exec > /tmp/hello.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to make a redirection happen from a variable.

Why?

The first thing the shell does with a command line is:

> Each line that the shell reads from the standard input or a script is called a pipeline; it contains one or more commands separated by zero or
>   more pipe characters (|). For each pipeline it reads, the shell breaks it up into commands, sets up the I/O for the pipeline, then does the following for each command (Figure 7-1):

From: [Learning the bash Shell Unix Shell Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009656.do) . [Chapter Preview / Figure](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-the-bash/1565923472/ch07s03.html) . [Pdf](https://doc.lagout.org/operating%20system%20/linux/Learning%20the%20bash%20Shell%20-%20Unix%20Shell%20Programming.pdf)

That means that even before starting with the first word of a command line, the redirections are set up.
The "Parameter Expansion" happens quite a lot latter (in step 6 of the Figure).

There is no way to set up redirections after a variable is expanded.

Unless ...

The "command line is reprocessed" using eval.

```
eval "$CMD"
```

But this comes with a lot of danger.
The command line is changed by the first processing in the 12 steps detailed in the book (quotes are removed, variables expanded, words split, etc.).

It is usually quite difficult to estimate all the changes and consequences before the line is actually processed.

And then, it is processed **again**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval to instruct the shell to reinterpret the variable content as a shell command:

```
eval $CMD
```

Comment: Thanks, theoretically speaking, is there nothing i can do to the contents of CMD for this redirection to happen. Consider the case where i can't modify the bash script, only have control over the CMD var - by passing as an env var, for example

Comment: No, that wouldn't be possible. The shell has to reinterpret the variable and the only way is to use `eval` command. The only thing you could do would be putting into `$CMD` some other script which would execute the command with redirection.

Comment: That should almost certainly be `eval "$CMD"` (otherwise you could end up with glob expansions, among other things) and it needs to come with a health warning.

Comment: Extending @rici's comment: `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a bug magnet. It's much too easy to get something you thought was just inert data to get up and start executing as code, or ... something. Double-quotes help a bit, but it's still something you should only use carefully, and as a last resort.